# Do I need to recreate my driver for each test?

Tags: selenium

I've just started using Selenium - currently I'm only interested in IE as it's an intranet site and not for public consumption. I'm using `IEDriverServer.exe` to set my browser sessions up, but I'm unsure as to whether I need to recreate it for each test, or if it will maintain atomicity of the browser sessions/tests automatically. I've not been able to find any information on this as most of the examples are for a single test rather than a batch of unit tests.

So currently I have

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{              
   _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
```

and

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TearDown()
{
   _driver.Close();
   _driver.Quit();
}
```

Is this correct or am I doing extra unnecessary work for each test? Should I just initialise it when it's declared? If so, how do I manage its lifecycle? I presume I can call `.Close()` for each test to kill the browser window, but what about `.Quit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Selenium with NUnit, but you don't need to recreate it every time. Since you are using MSTest, I would do something like this:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{              
   _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

[ClassCleanup]
public void TearDown()
{
   _driver.Close();
   _driver.Quit();
}
```

`ClassInitialize` will call code once per test class initialisation, and `ClassCleanup` will call code once per test class teardown / dispose.

Although this is still not guaranteed because the test runner may make several threads of the test:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/17/explaining-execution-order.aspx

You must also think about what kind of state you want to tests to start at each time. The most common reason for shutting down and starting a new browser session each time is then you can have a clean slate to work with.

Sometimes this is unnecessary work, as you've pointed out, but what is your tests starting point?

For me, I have one browser per test class, with a method to sign out of my web application and keep at the login page at the end of each test.

Comment: Thanks for the info, hope this will help others who are wondering the same!